# How to limit the text so it doesnt go outside of the input box?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When we type a lot of caracters, the letters start going outside the bar. We don`t want this... please help me to solve this problem

```
<div id="tasks-container">
        <div id="tasks-header">
            <h2>Type your next Task:</h2>
            <form action="" id="add-task-form">
                <input type="text" id="task-title" placeholder="What do you need to do?">
                <button id="add-btn" type="submit" >
                    <ion-icon name="add-outline"></ion-icon>
                </button> 
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="tasks-list-container">
            <h2>These are your Tasks:</h2>
            <ul id="task-list">
                <li class="task-box template hide">
                    <span class="task-title"></span>
                    <ion-icon class="done-btn" name="checkmark-outline"></ion-icon>
                    <ion-icon class="remove-btn" name="close-outline"></ion-icon>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can use the `maxlength` attribute to specify the maximum number of characters.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the text from overflowing outside the bar, you can apply CSS styling to limit the width of the input field. Here's an example of how you can modify your code to address this issue:

```html
        <div id="tasks-container">
    <div id="tasks-header">
        <h2>Type your next Task:</h2>
        <form action="" id="add-task-form">
            <input type="text" id="task-title" placeholder="What do you need to do?" style="width: 200px;">
            <!-- Adjust the width value as per your requirements -->
            <button id="add-btn" type="submit">
                <ion-icon name="add-outline"></ion-icon>
            </button> 
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="tasks-list-container">
        <h2>These are your Tasks:</h2>
        <ul id="task-list">
            <li class="task-box template hide">
                <span class="task-title"></span>
                <ion-icon class="done-btn" name="checkmark-outline"></ion-icon>
                <ion-icon class="remove-btn" name="close-outline"></ion-icon>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the above code, I've added an inline style to the input element and set its width to 200 pixels. You can adjust this value based on your desired width. This will limit the width of the input field and prevent the text from overflowing outside the bar.

Comment: That doesn't prevent the text from overflowing. It simply scrolls it.